# AmbiguousMatchException when truing override parent ASP.NET controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

almighty All!

Second day passed... Need Help!

I have two controllers: base **DocumentController** and derived **InvoiceController** in ASP.NET C# WebAPI application**:**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("Documents")]
public class DocumentController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual IEnumerable<Document> Get()
    {
        ... //some implementation
    }
}
```

```
[ApiController]
[Route("Documents/Invoices")]
public class InvoiceController : DocumentController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public new IEnumerable<Invoice> Get()
    {
        ... //some implementation
    }
}
```

I need first of them to show all documents, and the second one to show invoices only

Classes **Document** and **Invoice** are also base and inherited one

```
public class Document { ... }
public class Invoice: Document { ... }
```

when I use **override** keyword in **derived** controller, like this:

```
public override IEnumerable<Document> Get()
```

everything works fine, except that I need a list on **Invoices**, not **Documents**

But when I use **new** keyword, like this:

```
public new IEnumerable<Invoice> Get()
```

I get an error:

*AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:*
*InvoiceController.Get*
*DocumentsController.Get*

It means, that I have two methods = one from parent "DocumentController", and another one from child "InvoiceController"

It can be solved by adding some additional route attribute to child controller - for example "aaa" - in this case I have two GET endpoints in child controller:
Documents/Invoices - with a list of Documents (inherited from the base class)
and
Documents/Invoices/aaa - with a list of Invoices (from the new implementation in derived class)

but that is ugly

tried use different route attributes and so on...

Comment: _Prefer a more composition based approach over inheritance. That will also save you problems like this one_ - don't understand what do you mean (((

_Also, your error message mentions CreditController, which isn't even included in your example_ - sorry, fixed - it was the result of "code simplification" for the question

Comment: Ok, I think I'v got it..  
Not to use inherited controllers, but the only one:  
  
````[ApiController]  
    [Route("[controller]")]  
    public class DocumentsController : ControllerBase  
    {  
        [HttpGet]  
        public async <IEnumerable<Document>> Get(string? FromDate, string? ToDate) { ... }  
  
        [HttpGet]  
        [Route("invoices")]  
        public async <IEnumerable<Invoice>> GetInvoices(string? FromDate, string? ToDate) { ... }  
    }````  
  
Thanks, man! So easy, so good!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to inherit the `InvoiceController` controller from `DocumentController` to represent the inheritance of your models / DTOs. So I would suggest to remove that for sure. If you wanted to leverage some existing functionality from the `DocumentController` you could dependency inject in an instance into your `InvoiceController` and apply whatever filtering logic you want there... BUT even better would be to use a new type `DocumentService` that's dependency injected into both controllers and contains all the common logic for retrieving documents.

To set up the matching routes of the `/documents/` -> `DocumentController` and `/documents/invoices/` -> `InvoiceController` you might need to be more specific on the controller actions to specifically put their route details to ensure there is no ambiguity.

```
[ApiController]
public class DocumentController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("/documents")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<Document> Get()
    {
        ... //some implementation
    }
}

[ApiController]
public class InvoiceController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("/documents/invoices")]
    public IEnumerable<Invoice> Get()
    {
        ... //some implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Reddog, thanks for your answer!

The idea was that some common functionality - like deleting and some more - is in the base DocumentsController, and the specific functionality - like inserting, listing and some others - in inherited ones.
Using two independent controllers, inherited from base one, I need to implement common functionality in both of them

Now I used one controller with additional route postfix, and its intermediate decision